# Close Javascript menu by clicking outside of menu

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, click

I want to close my Javascript menu by clicking outside of the menu. I am using [this menu](http://demo.joomi.ir/). I'm not professional, please tell me how to change my code to do that:

```
$("#theme_select").click( function () {
  if (theme_list_open == true) {
    $(".center ul li ul").fadeOut();
    theme_list_open = false;
  } else {
    $(".center ul li ul").show();
    theme_list_open = true;
  }
  return false;
});
$("#theme_list ul li a").click(function () {
  var theme_data = $(this).attr("rel").split(",");
  $("li.purchase a").attr("href", theme_data[1]);
  $("li.remove_frame a").attr("href", theme_data[0]);
  $("#iframe").attr("src", theme_data[0]);
  $("#theme_list a#theme_select").text($(this).text());
  $(".center ul li ul").hide();
  theme_list_open = false;
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to close that menu when the iframe area is clicked, you have to do that in the iframe. Try putting this in your iframe's document ready function:

```
$("html").click( function () {
    $(".center ul li ul", window.parent.document).fadeOut();
    window.parent.theme_list_open = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you use `$("#theme_select").click( function () {` for both open and close the menu. and use `$("#theme_list ul li a").click(function () {` to handle click on menuitem, which will close the menu after.

In fact there is simple solution to your problem. Use `$("#theme_select").click` for only open the menu, and `$("#theme_list ul li a")` for handle the link, and introduce `$(window).click` to close the menu.

```
function checkAndCloseMenu(evt) {
  var dropmaker = $('#theme_select')[0];
  for (var node = evt.target; node != document.body; node = node.parentNode)
    if (node == dropmaker) return false;  // check if click in the dropmaker
  $('.center ul li ul').fadeOut();
  $(window).unbind('click', checkAndCloseMenu);
}
$("#theme_select").click(function() {
  $(".center ul li ul").show();
  $(window).click(checkAndCloseMenu);
});
$("#theme_list ul li a").click(function() {
  var theme_data = $(this).attr("rel").split(",");
  $("li.purchase a").attr("href", theme_data[1]);
  $("li.remove_frame a").attr("href", theme_data[0]);
  $("#iframe").attr("src", theme_data[0]);
  $("#theme_list a#theme_select").text($(this).text());
  return false;
});
```

PS: may be you should give the menu and menuitems some class names, your selector is painful to read.